# Error with code that should sort students into a class role

Tags: python, sorting

### Aim of the code:

Write a program that takes a list of student names and sorts them to create a class roll. The list of names will be given on one line separated by a single space. The students' names will always be in title case (the first letter capitalized and the rest of the name in lower case).

It has to sort in alphabetical order.

What is has to output:

```
Students: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy
Class Roll
Alan
Ivan
Jodi
Macy
Peng
```

My code:

```
names = input('Students: ')
print('Class Roll')
output = names.sort()
print(output)
```

I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: was any of the answers useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate that output using the following code:

```
names = input('Students: ')
print('Class Roll')
output = sorted(names.split())
print(*output, sep='\n')
```

Note two things, `*output` is using unpacking the elements in the list, and I am using the parameter `sep` that allows you choose the separator of the elements you want to print. In other words, each element in the output is printed separated by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input on space characters, then sort the resulting list.

Also, the `sort()` method modifies the list in place, it doesn't return the new list.

If you print a list, it prints it on one line, with square brackets around it and quotes around strings. If you want to print each name on its own line you have to loop.

```
names = input('Students: ').split()
names.sort()
print("Class Roll")
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the code has to output the names in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it will print when you enter "done":

```
list_names = []
while True:
   a = input("Enter a name: ")
   if a == "done" or a == "Done" or a == "DONE":
        list_names.sort()
        print(list_names)
   else:
        list_names.append(a)
```

Comment: this won't print the output as the indicated format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn the string into a List of names, then call sort on the array, like so.

```py
   names_list = names.split(' ')

   #Although items in a List are 
   #normally sorted out of the box

   output = sorted(names_list) 

   print(output) #['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']

   #Note: if you want to print it one item at a time, you will 
   #have too loop through the List and print each of them. e.g.,

   for name in names_array:
       print(name)
```